# Creating working regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am not good with regex.  However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  I need a regex that will match "-E1 (" or "-E22 (" etc.  I am currently trying

```
var pattern = @"[-E][0-9]?\s\("
```

but it returns no matches for "S1-E2 (702)" or "S3-E16 (705)".

Any help would be great.  Using C#.

Answer (score 3):

With `[-E]` you are going to match `-` or `E`..not both

To match multiple digits use `[0-9]+`..`+` here is a quantifier to match 1 to many digits

So,it should be

```
var pattern = @"-E\d+\s\("
```

Comment: In this answer Anirudh has also changed [0-9] to \d in the example, both represent "all digits".

Answer (score 1):

How about simply doing..

```
var pattern = @"-E[0-9 ]+\("
```

Regular expression:

```
-E            '-E'
 [0-9 ]+      any character of: '0' to '9', ' ' (1 or more times)
 \(           '('
```

The following quantifiers are recognized as:

```
*      Match 0 or more times 
+      Match 1 or more times
?      Match 1 or 0 times
```

Or you could use:

```
var pattern = @"-E[\d ]+\("
```

Comment: This will allow both multiple spaces before the bracket and space(s) _within_ the digits - so would pick up "-E2 3 4 (" for example. The space should probably _not_ be inside the [ ] unless this is desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around -E. Plus it looks like you expect multiple digits, so use [0-9]+. The final regex would be like **-E[0-9]{1,2}\s(**. Replace **{1,2}** with **+** if you expect more than two digits.

Answer (score -1):

You shoulb be replaced your code with -E\d+